# bareword found where operator expected syntax error

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. Anyhow I tried to debug myself. But I couldn't nail it

The syntax error is

```
Bareword found where operator expected at D:\DevelopmentLab\softwares\sc-master\sc.pl line 468, near "s%/%_%gr"
syntax error at D:\DevelopmentLab\softwares\sc-master\sc.pl line 468, near "s%/%_%gr"
Execution of D:\DevelopmentLab\softwares\sc-master\sc.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

The code is

```
sub getBackupFileName {
my ($containerName, $volume) = @_;
my $backupFileName = $volume =~ s%/%_%gr;
return "${containerName}_${backupFileName}.tar";
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated..

Comment: Which version of Perl are you using. The results of running `perl -v `. The `r` option to the `s` command is newish. You code in the example compiles under Perl 5.20.2

Comment: I am using v5.12.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `/r` option on `s/.../.../` was added in Perl 5.14 (in 2011). If you're using an earlier version, your code won't work. I don't have an earlier version available to test on, so I can't tell for sure whether it would give the error message you're seeing.

The easiest fix to get this working on earlier versions of Perl would be something like this:

```
sub getBackupFileName {
  my ($containerName, $volume) = @_;

  (my $backupFileName = $volume) =~ s%/%_%g;

  return "${containerName}_${backupFileName}.tar";
}
```